# Flutter dash chat 2 mention is not working properly

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, chat

I am using dash chat 2 to implement chat UI, now I need to add mention facility in dash chat , when I trigger @ it should need to show an overlay having users in firebase. I fetched users and listed in overlay but the problem is, when I select any of the user from the overlay, the overlay still visible there it won't be hided till the app closes. Is anybody worked on dash chat2, then please help me, it would be appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.